# Does XAdES support a comment field?

Tags: xml, x509certificate, sign, xades4j

I am working on an XML signing module and at least due to the timestamp I voted to go with the standard (XAdES) and implement it alike that.

I was able to digg into the list of Roles that someone might have.

However seems like there is no definition of role names in the standard?

The actual question that aririses to me is: Does any signed? subtree of XAdES support to add an arbitrary comment text? People want to just add some remark, when they sign. Did the standard forsee something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct, there's no definition of role names on the standard.

Regarding the "remark" you want to add, that seems like something application-specific. As such, I suggest using a `ds:Object` element, place your content in it, and also sign it. In `xades4j` you can do this using [`EnvelopedXmlObject`](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningSignedResources#envelopedxmlobject).

Answer (score 0):

I found a part answer to my question:

So seems like XAdES does not forsee a comment/reason tag to use. So doesn't Dsig. Therefore one might be forced to invent own stuff. Make your own schema for another `<Object>` tag to be signed, as well.

But there is a hidden feature in Dsig: The tag `<SignatureProperties>`

as https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2005/11/03/adding-signatureproperties-to-signedxml/ lines out. There is this basically un-connected specified type `<SignatureProperties>` in the [xsd](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-SignatureProperties). This is meant to be used inside the `<Object>` tag to provide "standardized" information.

Backdraw: There is still no standardized ***id*** to use for standard-fields such as **reason**.

Answer (score 0):

I found another interesting regardint the *comment/reason* using a current MS-Office version. Eg. one with **OfficeOpenXML** as file format.

As depicted in that [office blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_leblanc/2010/05/30/office-2010-digital-signatures-and-xades/) they do have decided to go with **XAdES**, too. So looking into the signed and un-zipped docx file offers a `_xmlsignatures/sig1.xml` file with content partly depicted here:

```
<Object Id="idOfficeObject">
    <SignatureProperties>
        <SignatureProperty Id="idOfficeV1Details" Target="#idPackageSignature">
            <SignatureInfoV1 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/digsig">
                <SetupID/>
                <SignatureText/>
                <SignatureImage/>
                <SignatureComments>bfghfghf</SignatureComments>
                <WindowsVersion>6.1</WindowsVersion>
                <OfficeVersion>15.0</OfficeVersion>
                <ApplicationVersion>15.0</ApplicationVersion>
                <Monitors>3</Monitors>
                <HorizontalResolution>1920</HorizontalResolution>
                <VerticalResolution>1200</VerticalResolution>
                <ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth>
                <SignatureProviderId>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</SignatureProviderId>
                <SignatureProviderUrl/>
                <SignatureProviderDetails>9</SignatureProviderDetails>
                <SignatureType>1</SignatureType>
            </SignatureInfoV1>
        </SignatureProperty>
    </SignatureProperties>
</Object>
<Object>
    <xd:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xd="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#idPackageSignature">
        <xd:SignedProperties Id="idSignedProperties">
            <xd:SignedSignatureProperties>
                <xd:SigningTime>2016-10-11T11:35:03Z</xd:SigningTime>
                <xd:SigningCertificate>
                    <xd:Cert>
                        <xd:CertDigest>
                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                            <DigestValue>YBmOrWhKAPGgIl1wrGEI0NrC92Q=</DigestValue>
                        </xd:CertDigest>
                        <xd:IssuerSerial>
                            <X509IssuerName>CN=xxxxxxx DC=xxx, DC=xxx, DC=org</X509IssuerName>
                            <X509SerialNumber>1225454644xxx099413888</X509SerialNumber>
                        </xd:IssuerSerial>
                    </xd:Cert>
                </xd:SigningCertificate>
                <xd:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                    <xd:SignaturePolicyImplied/>
                </xd:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
            </xd:SignedSignatureProperties>
            <xd:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                <xd:CommitmentTypeIndication>
                    <xd:CommitmentTypeId>
                        <xd:Identifier>http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.2.2#ProofOfOrigin</xd:Identifier>
                        <xd:Description>Hat dieses Dokument erstellt und genehmigt</xd:Description>
                    </xd:CommitmentTypeId>
                    <xd:AllSignedDataObjects/>
                    <xd:CommitmentTypeQualifiers>
                        <xd:CommitmentTypeQualifier>bfghfghf</xd:CommitmentTypeQualifier>
                    </xd:CommitmentTypeQualifiers>
                </xd:CommitmentTypeIndication>
            </xd:SignedDataObjectProperties>
        </xd:SignedProperties>
        <xd:UnsignedProperties>
          ...
        </xd:UnsignedProperties>
    </xd:QualifyingProperties>
</Object>
```

We recognize this:

- there is an object embedded in the signature
- one signed property (`idOfficeV1Details`) is custom in a custom namespace.
- but it contains the comment in clear text.
- However there is more in the `<xd:CommitmentTypeIndication>`
- It has this `<xd:CommitmentTypeQualifier>bfghfghf</xd:CommitmentTypeQualifier>` which repeats the comment.

Thus one can assume: "Maybe it is enough to just include the CommitmentTypeQualifier as a container for the *comment/reason* and that's it". If you can go without your custom information type - there you go.